# Incompatibility with connection pooling using ODP.NET Managed 12c against Oracle Database 10g2

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis

Every now and then, I'm getting exceeded SESSIONS_PER_USER errors on multiple .NET applications using the managed version of ODP.NET 12c. These applications are hosted on a single, large Oracle Database 10g2 instance.

Apparently, there's an issue with connection handling, as the session limit of these two apps in question is 30 and 100, and it quickly escalates until depleting it completely. When DBA staff attempts to kill the sessions, these remain unreleased, in a 'KILLED' status, not reducing the number of available connections. Apparently, the Application Server (IIS 7.5) 'holds on' to these connections, forbidding any new requests to connect.

*Application 1 Connection String (with line breaks for better readibility)*

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = 1.2.3.4)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SID = MYDB)
    (SERVER = SHARED)
  )
);
User Id=USR_APP;
Password=********;
Pooling=True;
Max Pool Size=30;
Connection Lifetime=300;
Incr Pool Size=2;
Decr Pool Size=2;
Statement Cache Size=100;
Validate Connection=true;
```

*Application 2 Connection String (with line breaks for better readibility)*

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS_LIST=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=MYDB.MYDOMAIN.COM)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA=
    (Service_name=CBA1SHARED)
    (SERVER=SHARED)
  )
);
User ID=usr_app2;
Password=***********;
Connection Lifetime=300; 
Connection Timeout=30; 
Decr Pool Size=30;
```

I don't remember having these sort of problems with the Unmanaged version of ODP.NET 11, installing Oracle Clients on the App Server. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are all your connections inside `using` blocks in your code?

Comment: @mason, yes, they are

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the USR_APP and or USR_APP2 accounts may have exceed the maximum number of sessions that was allowed them to carry. In order to find out, query the DBA_USERS and the dba_profiles views.

e.g.

```
select username, profile from DBA_USERS where username like 'USR_APP%'

select profile,resource_name,limit from dba_profiles
where resource_name = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER'
```

If the SESSIONS_PER_USER is too low, either ask the DBA to increase the SESSIONS_PER_USER amount on the existing profile or create a profile dedicated for these accounts with a higher limit. The DBA should also account for the extra RAM that it takes to keep the additional sessions before they actually die, which could be significant on a system that is low on RAM.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the problem of the 'hanging' connections wasn't happening with previous ODP.NET libraries and no app has ever before crossed the SESSIONS_PER_USER limit.

Comment: I see. Maybe a higher limit will help, but the root cause will be addressed by a bug or by new parameters in the connection string that might have been introduced in 12c. Have you checked that?